# How does BreezeJS caches or stores data locally

Tags: breeze

How does BreezeJS caches or stores data locally? Does it use window.localStorage for caching/storing the retrieved data?  Or is there any other approach for BreezeJS to cache/store locally?

If it uses window.localStorage, what would be the key name would be?

The reason I want answers to these questions is: We will be creating lot of localStorage data for our application and we don't want to erase or overwrite BreezeJS localStorage data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breeze caches data in memory inside of instances of the Breeze.EntityManager.  It you want to persist this data locally then Breeze provides methods such as EntityManager.exportEntities and EntityManager.importEntities to serialize and deserialize the contents of the EntityManager cache to and from a string.  You can store or retrieve this string from any client side persistent data store, the most obvious being localStorage. There are examples of this in the DocCode sample in the Breeze zip.

In your case each export of the Breeze.EntityManager can be stored in local storage with a separate key, so there will be no issue of overwriting data unless you explicitly want to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do remember that you can count on no more than 5MB of browser local storage per origin ... that's for all uses. There's no way to know how much you've used. You get an exception when you run out. So be careful about how much you put in local storage no matter what you put there.